# how to import font-family in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9, theme

I am preparing magento homepage and i want to change the font-family as

> opensans

but that font family is not available in magento. how to import that opensans.

help me out here,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have using **magento 1.9 the you can easy call open sans font**.

Suppose you want to add [google](http://www.cssfontstack.com/Open-Sans) font then

you  need to use function `addLinkRel() of head class.`

```
   <default><!-- use for all pages -->
    <reference name="head">
  <action method="addLinkRel"><rel>stylesheet</rel><href>//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans</href></action>
    </reference>
    </default>
```

You need to add this code on your layout xml file

Then change on style.css file it relevant font

Comment: You are missing one / in the URL to use is protocol independent. should be //

Comment: thankl for feedback...