# Google fonts not working in Firefox

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-community, fonts, font-family

I just realised that Firefox won't show the Google font 'Josefin Sans' which I'm using in my Magento store. Chrome displays it correctly, though. I'm using Magento 1.7.

I wasn't sure about whether Firefox is able to use it *defacto*, so I followed the steps in https://web-experiment.info/articles/cat/faq/post/magento_google_fonts and saw no results.

I added the following to styles.css under \skin\frontend\default\custom_theme\css:

```
@font-face {
     font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
     font-style: normal;
     font-weight: 400;
     src: local('Josefin Sans'), local('JosefinSans'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/josefinsans/v9/xgzbb53t8j-Mo-vYa23n5j0LW-43aMEzIO6XUTLjad8.woff2) format('woff2');
     unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F,    U+A720-A7FF;
}
```

and defined a style as:

```
.header .slogan {
    margin-left: 300px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: Josefin Sans, Arial;
    margin-top: 61px;
}
```

But Firefox keeps not loading it. In Firefox developer edition, it's working fine. Any hint on what may be happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You've got an space in the url of woff2
This could be an error?

Comment: I just checked my file, there is no such a space. It must be a copy-paste error. Could be Magento 1.7 too old for woff2? I am new to those things and I'm not sure of what could be the cause.

Comment: Why are you on 1.7?
Could try implement http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64397/how-to-import-font-family-in-magento, but it say is for 1.9 ...

I'm seeing there's a lot of errors in mozilla with google fonts, check your version and check google errors.

Comment: I just tried, it's not working. On Microsoft Edge the font displays correctly.

Comment: Then the problem is the version of mozilla client.
Tell us which is the version you use, and try to provide us the link to check if we see it correctly.

Comment: I realised I had a dummy option checked in Firefox. So no coding question. Firefoz/Options/Content/Fonts&Colours --> "Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of my selections above".

Comment: Should probably change the title of this post.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to the Magento platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was a dummy one, but maybe someone in the future will have the same issue.
It was just that I had an option checked in Firefox, that can be found at

Options / Content / Fonts & Colours ---> Advanced section

the option is named "Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of my selections above". Just uncheck it and that should do it.