# How Can I change font in magento 1

Tags: magento-1

I am working with Mac and I need to change the font family of our website. Can you help me, please?

Comment: you can follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29698253/how-to-change-font-on-magento-1-9-store/29698797

Comment: you can follow this link [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64397/how-to-import-font-family-in-magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64397/how-to-import-font-family-in-magento)